# Use uglifyjs-webpack-plugin in `plugins` or in `minimizer` section of Webpack config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

When using the [`uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) in your Webpack config files, should the plugin be used in the `plugin` section (based on [this article](https://simonsmith.io/organising-webpack-config-environments)) as showed in the first webpack config below?

Or in the `minimizer` section, as shown in the second webpack config (based on [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin))?

*Using webpack@4.39.1, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0, node@12.6.0*

**webpack config #1**

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    }),
    ...
```

**webpack config #2**

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin()
        ]
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of web pack(i.e > 4), it is sufficient if you include only in `optimization: {minimizer: [] }` section